# Debugging nwjs app in VSCode

Tags: node-webkit, visual-studio-code, nw.js

I am using VSCode as my primary JS ide and currently working on a NWJS(node-webkit) app. I want use the debugger available in VSCode. Can anyone guide me through how the launchjs should look like.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try to below lauch.json. it is working for me.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/camera/app.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "externalConsole": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is from node.js... The question was for nwjs, and I have the same issue as well...